# Make a copy of a spreadsheet while keeping protected ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I hope this won't make me lose points but I have been looking everywhere and I can't find an answer:

1. I have a spreadsheet with protected ranges.
2. I make a copy of the spreadsheet.
3. Protected ranges are gone in the copy.

Is there a way of keeping the protected ranges in the new copy ?

If it is not possible, maybe use

```
var protection = spreadsheet.getRange('D1:G9').protect();
```

on the new copy?

But then I have no idea how to assign it to the new copy, as the script would be in the original spreadsheet and the copy of the spreadsheet has no Id before being created ...

Comment: [`getProtections()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getProtections(ProtectionType)) on the original sheet and [setting it on the new sheet's ranges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) ought to work

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you for getting involved. The problem with this solution is that it requires the destination Id (dstId) which I do not have at the moment of copying the file...@sinaraheneba thank you as well. I have checked getProtections().... The only problem is that there is no way of protecting the sheet against myself (the owner)....

Comment: The gist of the problem here is the following: I am the owner of the original sheet with protected ranges. This sheet must be copied by many other people while keeping the protected ranges so they can not accidentally change the cells. The problem is when these people make a copy of the original sheet, they automatically become the owners of these sheets which makes it impossible to protect the ranges against themselves...

Comment: @danymalibu Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your situation? 1. About `The problem with this solution is that it requires the destination Id (dstId) which I do not have at the moment of copying the file.`, can you explain the detail information? 2. About `This sheet must be copied by many other people`, can you explain the method for copying?

Comment: @danymalibu 3. Can you post new question by including the detail information for replicating your current situation. Because when your initial question and your comment are compared, your initial question is different from the situation of your comment. And also I think that your initial question will be useful for other users. So I would like to recommend to post the issue of your comment as new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue. I'm glad.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I followed your advice and posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57051589/maintaining-protected-ranges-while-copying-a-file

Comment: The method for copying is the easiest one: File, make a copy or spreadsheeturl/copy

Comment: As for the dstId, I do not have the Id of the copy of the file as I am working on the original one and I do not have the Id of a file that does not exist yet ( I haven't made the copy yet)

Comment: @danymalibu Thank you for your response. I proposed a workaround for your new issue. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 7):

- When a sheet of Spreadsheet is copied to other Spreadsheet, you want to also copy the protected ranges.

  - `a spreadsheet` of `Make a copy of a spreadsheet while keeping protected ranges` means a sheet in a Spreadsheet.

When Spreadsheet is copied, the protected ranges are also copied. So I understood like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Issue:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, when a sheet is copied to Spreadsheet using `copyTo()` of Class Sheet and the method of copyTo of Sheets API, the protected ranges are not copied. This situation is the same with the manual copy.

#### Workaround:

In order to copy the protected ranges, the protected ranges are required to be copied to the copied sheet. But when Spreadsheet Service is used for this situation, the script becomes a bit complicate. So in this answer, as a workaround, I used Sheets API. In this case, the object retrieved by the get method is almost the same with the request body of the method of batchRequest. So I used this.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google Services. And also, please set the variables of `srcId`, `srcSheetName` and `dstId`.

```
var srcId = "###"; // Please set source Spreadsheet ID.
var srcSheetName = "###"; // Please set source sheet name you want to copy.
var dstId = "###"; // Please set destination Spreadsheet ID.

var src = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcId);
var dst = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstId);
var sheetId = src.getSheetByName(srcSheetName).copyTo(dst).getSheetId();
var protectedRanges = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(srcId, {ranges: [srcSheetName], fields: "sheets/protectedRanges"});
var requests = protectedRanges.sheets[0].protectedRanges.map(function(e) {
  e.range.sheetId = sheetId;
  return {addProtectedRange: {protectedRange: e}};
});
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, dstId);
```

#### References:

- [copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)
- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)
- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

### Added:

About the following question,

> how can we adapt if the sheet itself is protected except some ranges?

In this case, the property of `unprotectedRanges` is required to be included as follows.

#### Sample script

```
var srcId = "###"; // Please set source Spreadsheet ID.
var srcSheetName = "###"; // Please set source sheet name you want to copy.
var dstId = "###"; // Please set destination Spreadsheet ID.

var [src, dst] = [srcId, dstId].map(s => SpreadsheetApp.openById(s));
var sheetId = src.getSheetByName(srcSheetName).copyTo(dst).getSheetId();
var protectedRanges = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(srcId, { ranges: [srcSheetName], fields: "sheets/protectedRanges" });

var requests = protectedRanges.sheets[0].protectedRanges.map(e => {
  e.range.sheetId = sheetId;
  if (e.unprotectedRanges) {
    e.unprotectedRanges.forEach(f => f.sheetId = sheetId);
  }
  return { addProtectedRange: { protectedRange: e } };
});
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, dstId);
```

Comment: ineresting! upvoted. how can we adapt if the sheet itself is protected except some ranges?

Comment: @Mike Steelson About your question of `how can we adapt if the sheet itself is protected except some ranges?`, I thought that when this is included in the above script, it might be also useful for other users. So I added the sample script by updating the answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thousand thanks to you Tanaike!

Comment: @Mike Steelson Thank you for replying. If that is useful, I'm glad.